# How to set the name of a class variable using iterations?

Tags: python, class, variables

So I want to iterate through a dictionary and for each key in the dictionary I want to make a class variable but the name of the class variable will not change according to the loop

for example:

```
fruits= {'pears': 3, 'strawberries': 5, 'apples': 2, 'watermelons': 1, 'oranges':4}

class Fruit():
   def __init__(self, fruits):
      for fruitname in fruits:
          self.fruitname = fruits[fruitname]
          #How do I change fruitname when it is "connected" to the self
```

I tried looking for some other questions on stackoverflow but couldn't really find the problem because I have no idea how I should call this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's where setattr () comes in:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_setattr.asp

Note that there are differences between `setattr( self, 'foo', 'bar')` and `setattr( Fruit, 'foo', 'bar')`

Also note that the python argparse Namespace has been doing that for some time and usually people prefer the dict over the attributes

Answer (score 0):

Use `setattr`

```py
fruits= {'pears': 3, 'strawberries': 5, 'apples': 2, 'watermellons': 1, 'oranges':4}

class Fruit():
   def __init__(self, fruits):
      for fruit_name, fruit in fruits.items():
          setattr(self, fruit_name, fruit)

fruit_instance = Fruit(fruits)
```

[`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=setattr#setattr) and [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=setattr#getattr) could be used to respectively get or set attribute on an object. [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=setattr#hasattr) could also be used to ask for existance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add all the dictionary values as instance attributes, either you can use a `setattr` call with  name and value, or  just update the `__dict__`.

For Eg. see below

```
fruits = {'pears': 3, 'strawberries': 5, 'apples': 2, 'watermelons': 1, 'oranges': 4}


class Fruit():
    def __init__(self, fruits):
        self.__dict__.update(fruits)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fruit = Fruit(fruits)
    print(fruit.pears)
    print(fruit.strawberries)
    print(fruit.apples)
```

prints out

```
3
5
2
```

Answer (score 0):

**Without** for-loop: you can create such class directly at run-time with `type`: you need to pass class name as string, tuple of parents, dictionary with methods, class attributes, ...

```
fruits= {'pears': 3, 'strawberries': 5, 'apples': 2, 'watermelons': 1, 'oranges':4}

f = type('Fruit', (object,), fruits)

# tests:
print(f)
print(hasattr(f, 'pears'))
print(f.pears)
```

Output

```
<class '__main__.Fruit'>
True
3
```